# Creating long text file in cmd

Tags: file, text, cmd

Simple question i need to create reset.css file with batch file. I know how to make short-text files but when trying to put in a long text it doesn't work.

Here's the text

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

I just need some command so i can paste this text to batch file so it can save it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape special characters and maybe use quotes! :)

here's what I got using [TextZipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/textzipper/)...

```
@echo off
echo Textzipper is writing the files...
echo     html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, >> "asd.txt"
echo h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, >> "asd.txt"
echo a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, >> "asd.txt"
echo del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, >> "asd.txt"
echo small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, >> "asd.txt"
echo b, u, i, center, >> "asd.txt"
echo dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, >> "asd.txt"
echo fieldset, form, label, legend, >> "asd.txt"
echo table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, >> "asd.txt"
echo article, aside, canvas, details, embed,  >> "asd.txt"
echo figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,  >> "asd.txt"
echo menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, >> "asd.txt"
echo time, mark, audio, video { >> "asd.txt"
echo     margin: 0; >> "asd.txt"
echo     padding: 0; >> "asd.txt"
echo     border: 0; >> "asd.txt"
echo     font-size: 100%%; >> "asd.txt"
echo     font: inherit; >> "asd.txt"
echo     vertical-align: baseline; >> "asd.txt"
echo } >> "asd.txt"
echo /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */ >> "asd.txt"
echo article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,  >> "asd.txt"
echo footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { >> "asd.txt"
echo     display: block; >> "asd.txt"
echo } >> "asd.txt"
echo body { >> "asd.txt"
echo     line-height: 1; >> "asd.txt"
echo } >> "asd.txt"
echo ol, ul { >> "asd.txt"
echo     list-style: none; >> "asd.txt"
echo } >> "asd.txt"
echo blockquote, q { >> "asd.txt"
echo     quotes: none; >> "asd.txt"
echo } >> "asd.txt"
echo blockquote:before, blockquote:after, >> "asd.txt"
echo q:before, q:after { >> "asd.txt"
echo     content: ''; >> "asd.txt"
echo     content: none; >> "asd.txt"
echo } >> "asd.txt"
echo table { >> "asd.txt"
echo     border-collapse: collapse; >> "asd.txt"
echo     border-spacing: 0; >> "asd.txt"
echo } >> "asd.txt"
echo Done.
```

Comment: seriously there is no other shorter way ?

Comment: Did you tested this with special chars `<>|&` ?

Comment: @Endoro TextZipper automatically escapes them :D

Comment: @MichałWesołowski well you could try AutoHotkey! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the same code that was in the other answer, but changed to allow easier editing and the correct filename.

```
@echo off
set "file=reset.css"
>>%file% echo     html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
>>%file% echo h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
>>%file% echo a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
>>%file% echo del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
>>%file% echo small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
>>%file% echo b, u, i, center,
>>%file% echo dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
>>%file% echo fieldset, form, label, legend,
>>%file% echo table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
>>%file% echo article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
>>%file% echo figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
>>%file% echo menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
>>%file% echo time, mark, audio, video {
>>%file% echo     margin: 0;
>>%file% echo     padding: 0;
>>%file% echo     border: 0;
>>%file% echo     font-size: 100%%;
>>%file% echo     font: inherit;
>>%file% echo     vertical-align: baseline;
>>%file% echo }
>>%file% echo /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
>>%file% echo article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
>>%file% echo footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
>>%file% echo     display: block;
>>%file% echo }
>>%file% echo body {
>>%file% echo     line-height: 1;
>>%file% echo }
>>%file% echo ol, ul {
>>%file% echo     list-style: none;
>>%file% echo }
>>%file% echo blockquote, q {
>>%file% echo     quotes: none;
>>%file% echo }
>>%file% echo blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
>>%file% echo q:before, q:after {
>>%file% echo     content: '';
>>%file% echo     content: none;
>>%file% echo }
>>%file% echo table {
>>%file% echo     border-collapse: collapse;
>>%file% echo     border-spacing: 0;
>>%file% echo }
```